# delete_user_meta : how to delete all the metadata of a given user (witout SQL)

Tags: multisite, users

on a multisite I delete a user with:

> wpmu_delete_user($user_id);

Fine, but unless I am confusing, it doesn't delete the metadata which may exist for this user...

delete_user_meta() seems to be the function to do this but I don't see how to delete ALL the metadata, without entering the metakeys.
(I wanted to avoid writing a DELETE query directly on wp_usermeta table)

Thanks for your help
Pierre

Answer (score 4):

Yes, it does delete the usermeta. [Here's the code it uses](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/4.5.3/wp-admin/includes/ms.php#L242):

```
$meta = $wpdb->get_col( $wpdb->prepare(
                      "SELECT umeta_id FROM $wpdb->usermeta WHERE user_id = %d", $id ) );
foreach ( $meta as $mid )
    delete_metadata_by_mid( 'user', $mid );
```

There's identical code in `wp_delete_user` (for the non-multisite case) and they use the same pattern for deleting taxonomy metadata, post metadata etc. so this seems to be the accepted way, without a direct DELETE.